# Reducing the size of content within a composition in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm having playback issues with a video I've rendered in After Effects. I need to adjust the composition and all the content to a smaller size. However, when I adjust the comp size the footage stays the same. Is there a way to reduce the whole lot together?

Thanks

Comment: It might be a good idea to look inside to see why you're having a playback issue in the first place. Have you scaled the footage? Are you using Audio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale down everything in your composition by pre-comping everything and then shrinking the size of that pre-comp. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "when I adjust the comp size the footage stays the same". If you mean that when you change the composition size, the footage extends beyond the new border of the comp, then pre-comping and scaling down the pre-comp should fix this.

Comment: perfect! Didn't think to pre-compise it. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without the added complexity of precomposing. Look in the **File> Scripts>** menu, there's a script there called **scale Composition.jsx**. Run it, type in the new width, height or percentage and hit the button. Done.

Scripts are a useful, but rather neglected part of the AE tool set.

Comment: Would you really consider that less "complex" than simply precomping?

Comment: Well maybe not less complex, but pre-comping has other side-effects. This script just changes the size of your comp without changing the comp's structure or any relationship between layers. Other than that it's pretty much the same amount of work. AFAIK it actually does it by creating a null, parenting everything to that null, scaling the null and then unparenting.

Comment: Using the scale comp thing doesn't work if you are using different comp sizes within another. when scaled down position and scale gets knocked.